# IExceptionHandler does not handle UnsupportedMediaTypeException

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, exception, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented an exception handler (`IExceptionHandler`). Its `HandleAsync` method is called when exceptions are thrown inside controllers.
However, when a wrong content-type is passed with the request and an `UnsupportedMediaTypeException` is thrown in the formatter, my handler is not called. Instead the default error message is returned

`{
    "Message": "The request entity's media type...
    "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter ...
    ...
}`

I would like to handle ALL exceptions. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch it with a global `ExceptionFilterAttribute`, and filter `HttpResponseException`, not `UnsupportedMediaTypeException`.

E.g.

```
httpConfiguration.Filters.Add(new MyHttpResponseExceptionFilterAttribute());
```

It turns out that `UnsupportedMediaTypeException` is actually wrapped up in an `HttpResponseException` by the time it hits the WebApi pipeline.

`HttpResponseException` is not intercepted by `IExceptionHandler`, because it is designed to transport an HttpResponsMessage out to the client. The `UnsupportedMediaTypeException` is automatically wrapped into an `HttpResponsMessage` by the framework, and thrown in a `HttpResponseException`. The message you see in the HTTP response says "UnsupportedMediaTypeException", but that is actually just the `Content` of the `HttpResponsMessage` (`HttpResponseException.Response.Content`).

Comment: Thanks @jordan-morris. +1 for explaing what's going on.